# How to make chat thread using DynamoDB AWS?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-dynamodb

I have an application in which there will be one chat button. That will open   a chat screen in which all user can add their messages.

It's like thread on which every user can add/read message in it.It's not like chatting application.

I am storing all users messages in one DynamoDB table and retrive from it.How can i know that there is any new entry in that DynamoDB so i will refetch new data. in firebase i can detect any new change in any nodes. But what is way in AWS DynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

As a DynamoDB Streams user, you can leverage the design patterns found within the KCL to process DynamoDB Streams shards and stream records. To do this, you use the DynamoDB Streams Kinesis Adapter. The Kinesis Adapter implements the Kinesis Streams interface, so that the KCL can be used for consuming and processing records from DynamoDB Streams - 
[AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.KCLAdapter.html)